# Kill long running apache processes automatically

Tags: apache-2.4

Is there an apache setting where I can kill processes that run longer than 90 seconds? I got a DDOS attack and almost ran out of memory because a bunch of apache process were running for a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Request timeouts**

Take a look at the Apache module `mod_reqtimeout`, the config setting used with it is `RequestReadTimeout`.

**Example**: Allow for 5 seconds to complete the TLS handshake, 10 seconds to receive the request headers and 30 seconds for receiving the request body:

```
RequestReadTimeout handshake=5 header=10 body=30
```

To enable the module run these commands:

```
sudo a2enmod reqtimeout            # enable mod_reqtimeout
sudo service apache2 restart       # Re-start Apache
```

For more details consult [Apache 2.4 mod_reqtimeout](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html)

**Response Timeouts**

On the response side, where a DDOS attack has induced lengthy PHP processing, look at `max_execution_time` PHP setting, which is normally set in php.ini.

The Apache `TimeOut` setting is for network I/O timeouts. It restricts the time Apache waits for a TCP packet from a client, and the time Apache waits for acknowledgement when a TCP packet is sent to a client.

Comment: I am on amazon Linux. I see LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so in /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf. Does this mean it is loaded?

Comment: To be certain - `apachectl -M` will list all loaded modules

Comment: I have the module enabled. It says their is a default value. Is this used even though I never set directive?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can of course override the settings in your config. Default for body is `RequestReadTimeout body=10,minrate=500`

Comment: What would you think is a reasonable value. I have a couple file processing uploads that could take 60-90 seconds but is rare

Comment: Well that of course depends on your site, what it does, your users expectations etc. In your case 90 seconds I would have thought, if you can't do anything about reducing the time taken to process large uploads.

Comment: Using the default value. If the body is very small what would the timeout be?

Comment: Ideally no more than 30 seconds.

Comment: With default settings (No directive placed but module enabled) I made a simple script `<?php
sleep(120);
echo 'here';`
 and I actually got output after 2 minutes ( didn't die and outputted here). I do have an ALB in front of web server if that makes a difference.

Comment: Your test is on the response side, not the request side. If you want to test response timeout, set max_execution_time (in php.ini) and don't use sleep. Linux disregards sleep time as part of execution time. Try `<?php while(true); ?>`

Comment: Ah ok. What about a long running mysql_query...does that count a execution time?

Comment: Yes it will do.

Comment: hmm I have logs in new relic where a query took 115 seconds...I would think that the apache process would have been killed before it was allowed to run that long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97116/discussion-between-suspectus-and-chris-muench).